# Failure to find org.osgi:org.osgi.service.jaxrs:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, jax-rs, pax-web

I wanted to analyse the samples for JAX-RS for Pax-Web.

However, I can't import it to Eclise or compile with Maven because the following maven dependency can't be found:

```
org.osgi:org.osgi.service.jaxrs:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I was trying to find the library org.osgi.service.jaxrs, but got no success with Google or Maven repository...

What is this library? Is it a project that has changed name? How to get those samples to life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's available from the official OSGi sonatype repository. 
And actually also configured in the Pax Web root pom. 
See also [here](http://One%20of%20the%20biggest%20changes%20to%20the%20context%20that%20Agile%20brings%20is%20that%20the%20whole%20team%20does%20project%20management,%20not%20just%20the%20project%20manager.)

It contains the following location for an extra repository:

```
    <repository>
        <id>osgi-releases-and-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/osgi/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
```